# How can i improve my code? about elements not repeat

Tags: javascript

i want to know if the element already exist in my list, for that i have the exist function

```
function exist(colection,newItem,newIndex) {
    let theName = changeIndexOnName(newItem,newIndex)
    const exist =  colection.find( item =>(theName === item.name))
    return !!exist
}
```

I don't want the names of my elements to be repeated, that's why I am listing them like this: (element-1, element-2, element-3...element-n) by this function changeIndexOnName().

```
function add(colection, newItem) {
    let allowedIndex = 0
    while(exist(colection, newItem, allowedIndex)){
      allowedIndex++
    }
    newItem.name = changeIndexOnName(newItem.name, allowedIndex)  
    colection.push(newItem)
    return colection
}
```

up there once I have the number available then I change the name of the number.  `newItem.name = changeIndexOnName(newItem.name, allowedIndex)`

this for is the begining, i have two arrays, the new elements i want to put into the older elements list

```
for (const e of newElements) {
   add(olderElements, e)
}
```

Comment: Just out of interest: is there any purpose behind this whole naming game? Or, in other words: What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: @CarstenMassmann the elements are actually images, an image should never have the same name as another one, because firebase does not upload repeating files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly find new index using `filter` as `let allowedIndex = colection.filter(item => item.name.split('-')[0] === newItem.name).length;`.

Try it below.

```js
let olderElements = [{name: "Collection"}];
let newElements = [{name: "Collection"}, {name: "Collection"}];

function changeIndexOnName(name, allowedIndex) {
  return name + (allowedIndex === 0 ? "" : ("-" + allowedIndex));
}

function add(colection, newItem) {
  let allowedIndex = colection.filter(item => item.name.split('-')[0] === newItem.name).length;
  newItem.name = changeIndexOnName(newItem.name, allowedIndex)
  colection.push(newItem)
  return colection;
}

for (const e of newElements) {
  add(olderElements, e);
}

console.log(olderElements);
```

Comment: if is the first should not have the number "Collection-0" should be just "Collection"

Answer (score 0):

If we have no information about the inside of `changeIndexOnName()`, it will be faster to first keep all the existing names in a set before.

```
function add(colection, newItem) {
  let names = new Set(collection.map(item => item.name))

  let newIndex = 0
  let newName = changeIndexOnName(newItem, newIndex)

  while(newName in names) {
    newName = changeIndexOnName(newItem, ++newIndex)
  }

  newItem.name = newName
  colection.push(newItem)

  return colection
}
```

But if we know that the name is `image-XX` you can extract the `XX` part with some regexp (I use a simple `split` in function `extractIndex` in the example below)

```
function add(colection, newItem) {
  const extractIndex = name => Number(item.name.split("-")[1])
  let maxIndex = Math.max(...collection.map(extractIndex))
  
  newItem.name = "image-" + (maxIndex+1)
  colection.push(newItem)

  return colection
}
```

The code above finds the max index, and use `max+1` as next index.
Note that in production code you'd have to look for overflow and name parsing errors.

*But* if I were you I'd:

- use a random unique index, for example made from the timestamp and a random number
- store the set of already allocated indexes in a set if the risk of index collision exists